# TestNG Annotations-Cases skipping

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have created two testng classes and I have included those class names in below test suite and I ran the cases. But I see quitApplication test being skipped. Please help.

```
public class GmailLogIn {
static WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void startBrowser() {
        /*
         * System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
         * "E:\\Selenium drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); driver= new
         * ChromeDriver();
         */
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    Assert.assertTrue(url.contains("identifier"));
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "startBrowser")
public void loadApplication() throws Exception {
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("leninkumaryenni");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='RveJvd snByac']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Lenin2925");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='RveJvd snByac']")).click();
    String text = driver.findElement(By.className("ZrQ9j")).getText();
    Assert.assertEquals("Len", "Len");
}
}

    public class Test2 {
    @Test()
    public void quitApplication(WebDriver driver) {
        driver=GmailLogIn.driver;
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Test2 belongs to similar class and you have executed run as testng suite from gmail login alone. This case is similar to having two java class files with each having a main method and you have executed the main method from class A alone and worrying class B main method is not executed.

One easy fix for this , extend gmaillogin to test2 and run the test2 as testng suite. It will be read as class test2 extends gmaillogin.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Your code looks good but your setup may be having a bug.

### The Problem:

As you mentioned `I have included those class names in below test suite`, so when you  execute the suite you will see a `org.testng.TestNGException` with the error as `Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [quitApplication] with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]` because in **Test2** Class you have defined **quitApplication()** method to accept a `WebDriver` instance i.e. the `driver` as an argument as in `public void quitApplication(WebDriver driver)`. But you didn't pass it from anywhere.

### The Solution:

Here you have 2 solutions as follows:

1. The first solution (preserving your idea of executing 2 classes in a sequence on a common object i.e. `instance of the driver`) you have to pass the `WebDriver` instance i.e. `driver` into `Test2` Class and write a constructor so method `quitApplication(WebDriver driver)` gets executed.
2. The second solution would be easier. Take out the `quitApplication()` method from `Test2` Class and put it in `GmailLogIn` Class. Remove the argument `WebDriver quitDriver`. Add the annotation `@AfterTest` to `quitApplication()` method. Remove `(dependsOnMethods = "startBrowser")` from `loadApplication()` method. Instead of `@Test` put `startBrowser()` within `@BeforeTest` annotation.

Your working code will look like:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GmailLogIn 
{
    static WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void startBrowser() 
    {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    Assert.assertTrue(url.contains("identifier"));
    }

    @Test
    public void loadApplication() throws Exception 
    {
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("leninkumaryenni");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='RveJvd snByac']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Lenin2925");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='RveJvd snByac']")).click();
    /*String text = driver.findElement(By.className("ZrQ9j")).getText();
    Assert.assertEquals("Len", "Len");*/
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void quitApplication() 
    {
    System.out.println("Quiting Driver");
    driver.quit();
    System.out.println("Application Closed");
    }
 }
```

The output on the Console will be:

```
1500868669911   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1500868675056   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 60658
Jul 24, 2017 9:27:55 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Quiting Driver
1500868681737   Marionette  INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted
Application Closed
PASSED: loadApplication
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: @LeninKumar Glad to be able to help you. Thanks.